# How to disallow Windows 10 changing Fast Boot option after every update?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot

I have dual boot setup and from time to time, when I forget about Windows update and don't disable Fast Boot manually, I have difficulties booting into Linux system because of failed mouting NTFS device on boot.

I don't use Fast Boot at all (because of mentioned problem) and after every update it is forced on me.